# What is the chance of something not occurring?

Tags: probability

The question is as follows: In a sample of shall we say 1000 items, 65 come from source A and the rest 935 from source B. If a random sample is drawn from this population of 100 how do I work out the probability of NO samples from source A being drawn?

The formula for how to work this out would be appreciated

Comment: Seems it would be best to add a `self-study` tag. Also, is the 1000 the population? it is a tad unclear to me

Comment: I think the OP is treating the 1000 to be a finite population and the sample is taken without replacement.  The probability of not drawing A on the first draw is 935/1000  and on the second draw (934/999) since A was not drawn on the first draw.  Continue this way untill you get to 835/900. Then multiply these probabilities together.  It should be a pretty small number.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the axiom of conditional probability, if you were to randomly draw $k$ items from an urn of $N$ (where $x$ items are from *source B*, $N-x$ from other source), then the probability that all items drawn will be from *source B* is given by: $$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{x-i}{N-i}$$

More specifically, if you were to draw $10$ items from an urn of $100$, where $35$ are from *source B*,  i.e. $k = 10$, $N = 100$ and $x = 35$, then probability can be calculated by

$$\frac{35}{100} \times \frac{34}{99} \times \frac{33}{98} \times \frac{32}{97} \times \frac{31}{96} \times \frac{30}{95} \times \frac{29}{94} \times \frac{28}{93} \times \frac{27}{92} \times \frac{26}{91}$$

Upon the first draw there are 35 *source B* items out of 100 in the urn, and you are assuming the item will come from those 35. Upon the second draw there are 34 *source B* items out of the 99 remaining, again assume you get one of the 34, and so on.